# Google Sign In not returning name, picture, given name, family name on iOS but works on Android

Tags: android, ios, google-signin, google-oauth

I use id_token to communicate with Google Oauth APIs.
Here's the response I get by using the id_token from Android Google Login.
[image: Android]
But this is the response I get by using the id_token from iOS Google Login. Some fields are missing. Am I missing something?
[image: iOS]

I'm using the same account.

Answer (score 1):

[Please read all step carefully.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth)

> These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens

```
iss,sub,azp, aud,iat,exp
```

> These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the
>   "profile" and "email" OAuth scopes to the application.

```
email, email_verified, name, picture, given_name, family_name, locale
```

**Conclusion:**

It seems like you do not give `permission` to access profile while doing login with iOS Device.

Comment: I already added "profile" and "email" scopes. I can get profile info in client (iOS) but not in backend.

Comment: Can you please your token?